# WebGL Float modulus behaviour

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I am experiencing strange behaviours for below fragment Shader:

```
varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;

uniform float rows;

void main() {

    float testNumber = 7.0;
    vec4 outputColor =  vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    if(rows == testNumber) {
        if(worldSpaceCoords.x < 0.5) {

            outputColor.x = mod(floor(testNumber * worldSpaceCoords.y), rows ) / rows;

        } else {

            outputColor.x = mod(floor(testNumber * worldSpaceCoords.y), testNumber ) / testNumber;

        }

   } else {

        outputColor  = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

   }

   gl_FragColor  = outputColor;

}
```

The "testNumber" variable is just my control variable to check that the passed in uniform "rows" is actually what it should be.

Some numbers of the uniform "rows", gives a strange behaviour. Below is an example where it's set to 9.0 (with testNumber set accordingly).

[image]

This result is expected. However, setting rows to 7.0 (and testNumber accordingly), it looks like this:

[image]

Clearly something is not working as it should. Any ideas why? I have tried to set the precision to lowp, mediump and highp without any difference.

Thanks

Comment: @Rabbid76 Nothing particular - the result stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely the result of imprecise floating-point math, which adheres to rules documented in the [GLSL ES Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf). The *highp* qualifier guarantees that the inputs and outputs of the *mod* operator are 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point numbers, but the calculation itself is not guaranteed to produce the same high precision. In particular, the modulus operator is defined in Chapter 8.3 as

> genType mod (genType x, genType y)
>
> Modulus. Returns x – y * floor (x/y).

The division operator *a/b* in this expression is guaranteed to have a precision of no less than 2.5 ULP for *b* (see chapter 4.5.1) and is typically computed as *a*(1/b)* since reciprocals and multiplications are cheaper than divisions. In your case, *1/testNumber* is a compile-time constant and is probably computed to a different (higher) precision than *1/rows*, which needs to be computed at run-time.

You could try using integer math instead of floating point, as the integer modulus operator *a%b* doesn't suffer from such precision issues.

Comment: Thanks, suspected it was related to floating-point math. Due to the GLSL version WebGL 1 is running, I don't think I am able to perform integer math like that?

Comment: You're right - WebGL 1 explicitly allows integers being mapped to floats: [GLSL ES 1.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf).
Assuming the cube visualization is for illustrative purposes only, is it possible to rewrite your problem such that it doesn't evaluate the function within a few ULPs of discontinuities?